# How to inject data in a .bin file in a post compilation script?

Tags: embedded, bootloader, firmware, build-system

### Purpose

I want my build system to produce one binary file that includes:

- The bootloader
- The application binary
- The application header (for the bootloader)

Here's a small overview of the memory layout (nothing out of the ordinary here)

[image: The wanted memory organization]

The build system already concatenates the bootloader and the application in a post-compilation script.
In other words, **only the header is missing.**

### Problem

What's the best way to generate and inject the application header in the memory?

### Possible solutions

- Create a .bin file just for the header and use `cat` to inject it in my final binary
- Use linker file to hardcode the header (is this possible?)
- Use a script to read the final binary and hardcode the header
- Other?

What is the best solution for injecting data in memory in a post compilation script?

Comment: My title is not very good. If you have any suggestions, they are welcome.

Comment: Please *edit your question* with the following information: What is the target (i.e. ARM, 68HC11, etc.)?  What is the tool chain (i.e. Gnu, Microchip, etc.)?  Do you know the format of the .bin file?  From reading the script that the tools use to stick bootloader and application, can you understand the process *thoroughly*?

Comment: `cat` is a perfectly valid way to create this kind of file

Comment: It seems very odd that you'd put a header in between two pieces already stuck together.  You need to supply the already requested missing details, and realistically the best solution is probably *fixing the build system*.  The kinds of things you are talking about doing would be more typical when you are creating your own final build system to combine pieces which were not previously packaged together.  If the bootloader or the application payload or the resulting images already have well known names, be sure to identify them, eg, if it's U-Boot, say so, don't simply say "the bootloader".

Answer (score 1):

[SRecord](http://srecord.sourceforge.net/) is a great tool for doing all kinds of manipulation on binary and other file types used for embedded code images.

In this case, given a binary bootheader.bin to insert at offset 0x8000 in image.bin:

```
srec_cat bootheader.bin −binary −offset 0x8000 −o image.bin
```

The tool is somewhat arcane, but the [documentaton](http://srecord.sourceforge.net/srecord-1.64.pdf) includes numerous [examples](http://srecord.sourceforge.net/man/man1/srec_examples.html) covering various common tasks.

Comment: Thanks this is useful to me. In other words, your strategy would be to have a post-build script dedicated to injecting the header with the help of the `srec_cat` tool. I like the `--offset` flag.

Comment: @gberth "strategy" is overstating it.  It is just a method amongst several.  Personally I'd combine the application in the same way.  Otherwise you will have two builds, one for the combination, and one for the application alone ( which presumably you need, otherwise the bootloader serves no purpose).